# Do I need the second "of" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> This means it isn't made of the same stuff it was made (of) years
>   ago.

Do I need the second "of"? Why or why not?

Comment: We attempt to eliminate the grammar tag. (Almost) Please don't tag your questions with it. See [*A proposed solution to the Grammar dilemma*](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/a-proposed-solution-to-the-grammar-dilemma-please-contribute-your-answers-t?cb=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This means it isn't made of the same stuff it was made of years ago.

It’s correct, but a little unwieldy.

Perhaps:

> This means it’s now made of different stuff than it was years ago.

Comment: This means it's made of the same previous stuff?

Comment: @Usernew, no. It means that years ago it was made of one thing and it is now made of something different.

Comment: Oops! my bad, I meant "it isn't." :(

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)